# Is there a way to change the URL in Mockup browser window in Draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

On the draw.io browser window, is there a way to change the URL from `http://www.draw.io` to something else?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it isn't possible for this shape. In the next release we'll add address and tab parameters. Generally you can do this for most mockup shapes: select a shape, go to format->style and in this window you can change optional parameters. The dialog is a temporary solution and there will be a better method soon.